# Retrieving Google drive folder contents versus Google docs folder - What is Different?

Tags: google-apps-script

How would this script be modified?  I would like to work this tutorial but I believe it was written before drive replaced docs.

Section 1: Embedding folders in a File Cabinet

Linking Google Docs Folders with Sites File Cabinet

Open the Script Editor in your Site.
Click **More Actions** > **Manage Site**.
In the left-hand sidebar, click **Apps Scripts**.
Click Launch Editor.
Copy and paste the following code into the editor.

```
function showFolderInSite() {
  var files = DocsList.getFolderById("PASTE_FOLDER_ID_HERE").getFiles();
  var page = SitesApp.getPageByUrl("PASTE_PAGE_URL_HERE");
  for(i in files){
    page.addWebAttachment(files[i].getName(), '', files[i].getUrl());
  }
}
```

Open your folder in Google Docs and copy the folder ID from the URL that is in the browser window. The folder ID is everything after the `folder.#.` portion of the URL. 
For example, given the following example url

https://docs.google.com/?tab=mo&authuser=0#folders/folder.0.0B3xR7WfXrj7aOGY4Y2M3OWItZjAyYy00ZTM5LTg3MTgtNjNkYWZhZTZmYmU3

the folder ID is this section: `0B3xR7WfXrj7aOGY4Y2M3OWItZjAyYy00ZTM5LTg3MTgtNjNkYWZhZTZmYmU3`. Note that it is everything after the `folder.0.`. The following graphic also shows the folder ID:

Answer (score 0):

There are some minor changes in the way  folders url are constructed but the idea is always the same : the ID is everything thats is different between two items of the same type (2 spreadsheets, 2 folders ...that's just how they build up the urls)
In this example below, the ID is just eveything after `folders/`

ie the line of code to get the files in this folder would be like this :

```
var files = DocsList.getFolderById("0B3qSFd3iikE3TkN2THNDUnAwX2s").getFiles();
```

Hoping this will help you to finalize your tuto.

[image: typical folder url]

Note that some url are more complex in that some parameters are added behind the ID string (it is actually the case most of the time ;-)